# Need info about iOS bundle seed numbers

Tags: ios, bundle, provisioning, seed

This is a repost from the Xcode Developer's list.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html

I've been noticing recently that for our Enterprise development account, when on the iOS provisioning profile, we are not always getting provisioning profiles created with the same bundle seed.

Sometimes, it's

ABC1234567.

and sometimes it's

ZYX7654321.

(These are examples, not our real bundle seeds)

When creating app IDs ala the iOS provisioning profile, we always get prov profs created with the first bundle seed.  When creating development profiles, we also get prov profs with the the first bundle seed.

But, when trying to create distribution profs, we have either get Invalid Certificate (in the top left of the provisioning portal) or success but with the second bundle ID.

Can anyone tell us why we are getting two different bundle seeds, how it matters and why we have two ids?

When creating a new App ID, it (the provisioning portal) asks if we want to use the Team ID (I assume this is the first bundle seed) or the second one.

When creating a distro profile, what is odd is that it appears that our first certificate is invalid - the prov portal won't let us create a distro profile using it.  How can this happen?

Can an iOS app with the first bundie seed ID (they are both in the same Enterprise account) be distributed using a distro profile with the second ID?

TIA.